# Django - coercing to Unicode

Tags: django, unicode, typeerror

I am having a unicode problem and, as everytime I have something related I'm completely lost..

One of my Django template renders a TypeError :

```
Exception Value:    

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, long found
```

The line giving trouble is just a string ( which I want to use in a mysql query) :

```
query = unicode('''(SELECT asset_name, asset_description, asset_id, etat_id, etat_name FROM Asset LEFT OUTER JOIN Etat ON etat_id_asset=asset_id WHERE asset_id_proj='''+proj+''' AND asset_id_type='''+t.type_id+''' ORDER BY asset_name, asset_description) UNION (SELECT asset_name, asset_description, asset_id, 'NULL', 'NULL' FROM Asset WHERE asset_id_proj='''+proj+''' AND asset_id_type='''+t.type_id+''' AND asset_id IN (SELECT etat_id_asset FROM Etat)); ''')
```

What can be wrong here ?

Comment: What's inside t.type_id and proj?

Comment: Ok, I just found the official way of doing this in Django and it works fine. Sorry for wasting your time ! (It's like this : `Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])`)

Comment: If you want to just select everything from some table, you can do it event more efficiently: ``Person.objects.filter(last_name=lname)`` See Django ORM docs)

Comment: I know, but if you look at my question, me query is much more twisted than that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you figured out a better way to accomplish, but to answer the original question, in case you get that error again somewhere else in the project:

t.type_id appears to be a long integer. You cannot mix integers in strings unless you convert to string, this is really simple:

```
myString = 'some string with type id ' + str(t.type_id) + ', and whatever else you want in the string.'
```